# How to reserve vertical scrollbar in an ExtJS 4 grid panel?

Tags: grid, scrollbar, extjs4.1, placeholder

I'd like to know if there is a way to reserve space for a vertical scrollbar in a grid panel with ExtJS 4.1.1. I remember that I was able to do this with ExtJS 3, but maybe this feature was removed?

The grid has a fixed height so a scrollbar appears when the amount of rows exceeds the height of the grid. There is also a "delete" action that allows to remove each row one by one. The problem is that the action moves to the right when the scrollbar is not required anymore. This is the behaviour I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `reserveScrollbar`

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Auto-cfg-reserveScrollbar

Comment: Hi Brett :) I can't remember exactly what was the context, too many days have passed. Moreover, I'm quite sure that I have tried this property but with no result (ExtJS 4.1.1). I guess I have resolved the problem in an indirect way. Thanks anyway, I'll try to remember to update this page if I stumble upon this problem again.

Comment: Hi! So while it may be a moot point, it's worth mentioning that reserveScrollbar is valid for panels. One solution could be to nest the grid inside a panel that has reserveScrollbar set.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflowY: 'scroll'` as a config param for your grid.  See docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-overflowY.